# My animated graph does not allow me to use the blitting technique

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I have successfully created an animated graph using data from an opencv while loop. Movement on a camera is subtracted from the background creating white pixels, these pixels are averaged `average_int`, and then plotted on the y axis using the matplotlib `FuncAnimation()` function.

The problem is, I would like to use the program for research and the graphing lags the video too much so it needs to be optimized. The blitting technique is supposed to speed up the process 10 fold, but whenever I attempt to use it in the `FuncAnimation(blit=True)` there is no performance upgrade and the graph blinks on and off and never graphs correctly. I can't seem to find the problem. I thought that perhaps the Matplotlib windows is interfering with the opencv windows somehow.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from scipy import signal

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

_, first_frame = cap.read()

count = 0
peaks_frames = 1
peaks_diff = [1]
result_array = np.array([])

x_len = 60
x_len2 = 200
y_range = [-2, 100]
y2_range = [3, 12]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)

xs = list(range(0,60))
xs2 = list(range(0,200))
ys = [0] * x_len
ys2 = [0] * x_len2

line, = ax.plot(xs, ys, 'k')
line2, = ax2.plot(xs2, ys2,'b')

ax.set_ylim(y_range)
ax2.set_ylim(y2_range)


def animate(i, ys, ys2):
   ys.append(average_int)
    ys = ys[-x_len:]
    line.set_ydata(ys)

    ys2.append(peaks_frames)
    ys2 = ys2[-x_len2:]
    line2.set_ydata(ys2)
    return line, line2

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(ys, ys2),interval=120, blit=True)

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read( )

    difference = cv2.absdiff(first_frame, frame)
    difference = cv2.GaussianBlur(difference, (3, 3), 0)

    _, difference = cv2.threshold(difference, 18, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


    cv2.imshow('first frame (1)', first_frame)
    cv2.imshow('Original', frame)
    cv2.imshow('difference', difference)

    average = (np.average(difference))                                  
    average_int = int(average)                                          

    result_array = np.append(result_array, average_int)                 

    peaks_pos = signal.find_peaks_cwt(result_array, range(1,2,10))      

    peaks_diff = peaks_pos[1:] - peaks_pos[:-1]                         

    count = count + 1

    if count >= 30:                                                     
        peaks_frames = peaks_diff[-1]


    plt.pause(0.000001)


    key = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `plt.pause` draws the canvas. It is hence expected that there is no performance gain when using blitting.

Comment: Sorry I'm only about 3 weeks into programming, when you say it draws the canvas you mean the graph which the line is drawn on correct? Then is there a way for something else to draw the canvas so I can increase performance, or would I have to rewrite the animation code entirely?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you. When I said "it draws the canvas" I mean that it calls `fig.canvas.draw_idle()` internally; this is the command that takes the time you are trying to avoid with blitting.